# Playing png Sequence with transparency on ipad/safari

Tags: ios, html, animation, png, transparency

I´m looking for a way to play a png Sequence with transparency on a webpage that will only be viewed with ipad/safari.

As far as animated GIF and Flash are not possible I think that a HTML5 animation with transparent png-Files could be a way ...
The Tumult Hype Tool seems to offer a possibility but it is very time consuming to animate every single frame in a time line and I don´t know that tool at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it with Hype, but with those large image files you start seeing a performance hit after 7 or 8 images. For the carousel itself you're better off using a pre-built script like [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) or something similar.

As far as only making it viewable on iPad, you could do it with [media queries](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/). Put all your styles in the media query for iPad, and have all other queries just display a black screen or an error message or something.